# Connecting to Redis cluster using Lettuce lib and TLS (Trust store and key store)

Tags: java, ssl, redis, certificate, lettuce

I am able to connect to Redis via

```
redis-cli --tls --cert ~/cert/test/redis.example.com.chain.pem --key ~/cert/test/redis.example.com.key \
-h [redis-endpoint] -p 6379 
and
auth username password
```

And I'm trying to write Java code using Lettuce(ver 6.0.x), but not able to connect.

Here are the steps I tried:

1. creating key
   openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -keyout redis.example.com.key.pem -subj "/"
   openssl rsa -in redis.example.com.key.pem -out redis.example.com.key
2. 

I was able to connect to Redis cluster via Redis-cli command line

```
redis-cli --tls --cert ~/cert/test/redis.example.com.chain.pem --key ~/cert/test/redis.example.com.key -h redis.example.com.key.com -p 6375
```

auth username password
3. creating Key store

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in redis.example.com.chain.pem -inkey redis.example.com.key.pem -out keystore.p12
```

4. creating trust store

```
keytool -importcert -file root_ca.pem -destkeystore root-ca.truststore.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -alias root-ca
keytool -importcert -file corporate_root_ca.pem -destkeystore root-ca.truststore.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -alias cm-root-ca
```

6. Java code

```
          RedisURI redisUri = RedisURI.Builder.redis(enterpriseConfig.getEndpoint())
              .withSsl(true)
              .withAuthentication(userName, password)
              .withPort(port)
              .build();
          ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions topologyRefreshOptions = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
              .enablePeriodicRefresh()
              .enableAllAdaptiveRefreshTriggers()
              .refreshTriggersReconnectAttempts(3)
              .build();

          RedisClusterClient cluster = RedisClusterClient.create(redisUri);
          ClusterClientOptions clientOptions = ClusterClientOptions.builder()
              .topologyRefreshOptions(topologyRefreshOptions)
              .autoReconnect(true)
              .sslOptions(buildSslOptions())
              .build();
          cluster.setOptions(clientOptions);
          System.out.println("connecting ... ");
          return cluster.connect();
```

7. buildSslOptions()

```
  private static SslOptions buildSslOptions()
      throws KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    Map<String, String> clientCert = ConfigLoader.getConfiguration().getClientCert();
    if (clientCert != null){
      String baseDir = clientCert.get(CERT_BASE_DIR);
      String slash = "/";
      if (baseDir.lastIndexOf("/") == baseDir.length() - 1) {
        slash = "";
      }
      String keystore = baseDir + slash + clientCert.get(KEY_STORE);
      String keystoreType = clientCert.get(KEY_STORE_TYPE);
      String keystorePassword = clientCert.get(KEY_STORE_PASSWORD);
      String truststore = baseDir + slash + clientCert.get(TRUST_STORE);
      String truststoreType = clientCert.get(TRUST_STORE_TYPE);
      String truststorePassword = clientCert.get(TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD);

      KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);
      FileInputStream keyStoreFile = new FileInputStream(keystore);
      keyStore.load(keyStoreFile, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

      KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(truststoreType);
      FileInputStream trustStoreFile = new FileInputStream(truststore);
      trustStore.load(trustStoreFile, truststorePassword.toCharArray());

      KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
      TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

      return SslOptions.builder()
          .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
          .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
          .build();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The Errors I got

```
connecting ...
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to establish a connection to Redis Cluster

...
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh$CannotRetrieveClusterPartitions: Cannot retrieve cluster partitions from [rediss://[username_masked]:*****************@[redis_url]:6379]

...
Details:
    [rediss://[username_masked]:*****************@[redis_url]:6379]: ERR command is not allowed

    Suppressed: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR command is not allowed
```

What did I miss?